# Getting wrong answer with reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I always mess up reduction of order.

$y''-4y'+4y=0$ has solution $y_1=e^{2x}$ using reduction of order
$$y_2=y_1 \int \frac{e^{-\int{p(x)dx}}}{y_1^2}dx=e^{2x} \int \frac{e^{-(-4x)}}{(e^{2x})^2} dx=e^{2x} \cdot e^{2x}+C=e^{4x}+C$$

but the answer key gives $y_2=xe^{2x}$

Comment: Er... $\int \frac{e^{-(-4x)}}{(e^{2x})^2} dx = \int 1 dx = x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to regard that $(e^a)^b=e^{a·b}$ and not $e^{a^b}$. Then the cancellations lead to the given solution, if also distributivity is applied correctly.